# $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is not a Dedekind domain.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

I have to prove the following statement:

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the ring of all algebraic integers in (a fixed choice of) $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is not a Dedekind domain.

> Which one of the three properties of a Dedekind domain does the ring $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ not satisfy ?

We know that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (for my part the proof was given in class but if someone wants it, I can give it).

I found that it's not noetherian because there is a strictly ascending chain of ideals: $\lbrace (2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}) \rbrace_{n = 1}^{\infty}$.

> And I have to prove that every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

Yes, I have to do it to be sure the noetherian property is the only one which is not true. But I have no idea how to do it. I thought about doing it by contradiction... can't seem to get it very far. Is it a good direction ? If it is, how do I go on ? If it is not, what do I do ?

Jérôme

Comment: What is your definition of a Dedekind Domain?

Comment: Well, there it is. An integral domain is a Dedekind domain if it is noetherian, integrally closed in its field of fractions, and every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$. Let $O_{K}$ denote the ring of integers of a number field $K$. Then $O_{K}\subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ for every number field $O_{K}$. Notice that $ O_{K}/P\cap O_{K} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P $ is a monomorphism. Observe also that $P\cap O_{K} \neq 0$ for every prime ideal $P$ since $P \cap \mathbb{Z} \neq 0$.
Finally, notice that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P $ is integral over $O_{K}/P\cap O_{K}$ implying that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P$ is a field. This is because $P\cap O_{K}$ is a non-trivial prime ideal and hence a maximal ideal in $O_{K}$ and any domain which is integral over a field must itself be a field. As $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P$ is a field, $P$ is maximal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And sorry, I don't understand what you are doing. Probably because I don't know by heart all the results and theorems you use implicitly.

Comment: You can tell me what is not clear. There is only one theorem that is being used which I suspect you probably don't know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. If I understand, you use the monomorphism to prove that because $P \cap O_{K}$ is maximal, so is $P$.

The theorem I lack is, I'M taking a guess, the one saying things about ideals in fields ? Is that why you prove that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P$ is a field ? I don't remember it.

Comment: If a domain is integral over a field, then the domain itself is a field. Is this the theorem you are talking about?

Comment: In fact I don't understand why you prove it's a field. And I'm not quite sure of how you prove $P$ is maximal, it seems lost among other things I don't need.
It's interesting but here I just want to prove that every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: You will find the following theorem in any basic algebra textbook (such as Herstein): Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is maximal.

Comment: God yes... found it hidden in my notes. I can't thank you enough for your patience.

Comment: Why is $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/P$ integral over $O_{K}/P\cap O_{K}$? Is it because $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is integral over $\mathcal O_K$?

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb Z\subset\overline{\mathbb Z}$ is an integral ring extension. By [Cohen-Seidenberg Theorem](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rse/205a.1.13f/cohen_seidenberg.pdf) we have $\dim\mathbb Z=\dim\overline{\mathbb Z}$. Since $\dim\mathbb Z=1$ you get $\dim\overline{\mathbb Z}=1$, and therefore every nonzero prime ideal is maximal in $\overline{\mathbb Z}$.